Optimized build for pip
This question is similar to
Python Setuptools Distribute: Optimize Option in setup.py?,
but the question was asked 11 years ago and I hope that the python ecosystem developed further.
We have a code where we would like to use assert for checks of invariants that have sometimes expensive scaling.¹ We can use assert for small problem sizes in a test suite, but do not want the asserts in production code. I know that one could execute python -O when invoking our code, but is there a way to strip asserts away at installation time?
(Similar to -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug vs. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release for compiled languages.)
